# How to get Multiple select values in add row loop using php?

Tags: php, html, html-select, multiple-select

My code is in select tag with multiple option

```
<select name="select[]" multiple>
   <option value='a'>a</option> 
   <option value='b'>b</option>
</select>
```

This code is in add row. so multiple rows i need to select the multiple option. 1st time am selecting 'a and b' and 2nd time selecting 'b'.After submitting the form, using php receiving the values and it is

```
Array(
    [0]=>a,
    [1]=>b,
    [2]=>b
)
```

but i need as

```
Array(
    [0]=>Array ( 
        [0] => a,
        [1] => b 
    )
    [1] => 
    [2] => b
)
)
```

Someone help me about how to declare variable for this and to receive using php. Prior thanks for all

Comment: How are you creating the rows?  In a PHP loop?  With Javascript?  Ultimately, you want to create a multi-dimensional array like `name="select[0][]"` and `name="select[1][]" `, but how you do that depends on how your rows are created.

Comment: do you have multiple dropdowns? or if one then use session

Comment: Is this in a GET form? how are you persisting the values between requests? Can you add a bit more detail to the question about how this is working currently? I think it's apparent enough what your goal is, but I'm not clear on what you're starting with.

Comment: _"1st time am selecting 'a and b' and 2nd time selecting 'b'"_ - Please elaborate about what you mean by _"1st time"_ and _"2nd time"_.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  I _think_ that's related to "so multiple rows i need to select the multiple option".  That makes me think OP is adding/creating multiple instances of what we're seeing above, which is why I asked what I asked.

Comment: Yeah, I am using javascript for add row. May I know how do i do this 'name="select[0][]" and name="select[1][]"' @PatrickQ

Comment: @GowriShankar  Please include that Javascript code within your question

Comment: `addhtml += '<tr><td><select name="name[][]" multiple ><option value="Test">Select</option><option value=""></option></select></td></tr>';`

`$("#addfield").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#addtable").append(addhtml);
}`

Comment: This is my html code to be added if add row is clicked and script is there @PatrickQ. How can i make the name[][] to be name[0][], name[1][] etc through the script?

Comment: `var sr_no = $(document).find('#addtable tbody').find('tr');
            var row_length = sr_no.length <= 0 ? 1 : sr_no.length;

            for(var i=0; i<=row_length;i++) {
                $(document).find('#addtable tbody').find('tr').eq(i).find('td:first').html(i+1);
            }`

If am using this in my script , am getting the count of rows in first row using this "$(document).find('#addtable tbody').find('tr').eq(i).find('td:first').html(i+1);".  But dont know how to get as value and how to use in the place of name[][] variable in 1st index of this array.. Can anyone help @PatrickQ